# How do start innodb in recovery mode using docker

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, innodb

My database won't start after restarting the server.
it throws the following error;

[ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=1106, page number=4119] log sequence number 29970252505 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 29967893604.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.

So my question is how do I start innodb in recovery mode using docker?

Answer (score 2):

To start innodb in recovery mode, you need to add the following line to the `my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 0
```

0 is normal use. You can read more about the different levels here:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-recovery-modes/

Usually, the recommendation is to start from the lowest possible value (e.g. try 1), and if that doesn't work, then increment up. Possible data corruption may occur the higher level you use.

If you already have the `my.cnf` file mapping between your host and the container, then just make the modification on your host and start the Docker service.

If you don't have the `my.cnf` file, then you probably have the default variables defined. One of the easiest options is to:

1. Start a new container with the same image while mapping the container's `/tmp` folder to your local machine `/path-on-host/tmp`.
2. Go into the container (e.g. `docker exec -it container_name bash`) and copy the my.cnf file to the tmp folder (`cp /etc/my.cnf /tmp`) and shut down the container. The location of the `my.cnf` file is either in `/etc`, or on some versions it can be in `/etc/mysql`.
3. Modify the `my.cnf` file on your host machine by setting the `innodb_force_recovery = x`
4. Add the `my.cnf` to the correct location on your original container, e.g. using Docker Compose:

```
volumes:
      - '/path-on-host/tmp/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf'
```

or when using `docker run`

```
--mount type=bind,src=/path-on-host/tmp/my.cnf,dst=/etc/my.cnf
```

Comment: No need for all those steps - one can extract the used `my.cnf` from the container, edit it and then reinstall it with the `docker cp` command: `docker cp mycontainer:/etc/my.cnf my.cnf`

Comment: Good point about using `docker cp` although I believe it will get more complex to make sure the settings are right. You will need to go into the container and restart the MySQL service.

Also, you will probably need to modify the `innodb_force_recovery` variable multiple times. It's easier if the file is mounted, because then you can just edit it locally and save - it is automatically on the container. Otherwise, you need to copy it each time you make a change to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can add it in the 'command' line (temporally!) like any other init arguments

```
services:
  mariadb:
    image: "mariadb:10.6.4"
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: **
      MYSQL_DATABASE: **
      MYSQL_USER: **
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: **
    command: -–innodb_force_recovery=4 --lower_case_table_names=1 --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_bin --innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0
```

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-recovery-modes/#recovery-modes